# On an A-Frame component, how do you share data between functions?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I'm making an A-Frame component and I want to share data between functions like `init` and other custom component handlers.

I figured out how to add to the component schema to allow for input from the DOM to set a variable using `this.data` following this doc:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/core/component.html#component-prototype-properties

However I am having trouble, sometimes the value of `this.data` reverts back to the initial state from the DOM, not reflecting runtime modifications. Is there a better way to share data across a component?

Comment: Please share your code so it would be easier to help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two recommended ways of storing data in an A-Frame component, similar to public and private properties.

**Schema (public)**

Properties declared in the component's schema are public, and can be set with `setAttribute` and accessed with both `getAttribute` and `this.data.____`. **NOTE:** It is *not* safe to modify `this.data` directly, because A-Frame will overwrite the data when receiving updates from the DOM.

HTML:

```
<a-entity foo="bar: 10"></a-entity>
```

JS:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  schema: {
    bar: {default: 25}
  },
  init: function () {
    console.log(this.data.bar); // 10

    this.data.bar = 5; // THIS CHANGE MAY BE LOST.
  },
  doStuff: function () {
    console.log(this.data.bar); // 10
    this.el.setAttribute('bar', 'foo', 15);
    console.log(this.data.bar); // 15
  }
});
```

**Properties (private)**

For data meant to be used within a component, you can also assign them directly to `this`. This is the best option when data will only be used within the component, and doesn't need to be declared in the HTML.

JS:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function () {
    this.baz = 'hello';
    console.log(this.baz); // hello
  },
  doStuff: function () {
    console.log(this.baz); // hello
    this.baz = 'bonjour';
    console.log(this.baz); // bonjour
  }
});
```